# how to create text with clear button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uibutton

Just like attached screen shot, I want to show some text with a remove button associated.
Any library/guide or sources welcomed.

Don't hesitate to update the question title because I am unable to get it from google.

[image]

Comment: This is a custom UI with views that contain text and an X button. You could use a UICollectionView to lay it out. Search for Tags on Cocoapods.org

Comment: You are looking to replicate a view from the Facebook website, but you should try to replicate this part from the iPhone app of Facebook. What you have asked is totally doable, but personally I feel but it would be better if you implemented what the iPhone app does. Just my opinion.

Comment: You have to go with custom view that has one label and button. also if you want click event make custom delegates of that custom view.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `UIView`. Add `UILabel` for the text and `UIButton` for remove (x) button.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple

1) Create a `UIView` and set the `backgroundColor` to `blue` or whatever color you need.
2) create a `UILabel` with your `text` and add a `subView` to the `view` you made in step 1.
3) create a `UIButton` with text `x` and add it as the `subView` to the `first view`.

Done. I hope it helps.

Comment: And Get the text width dynamically and set the parent view witdth = (text width + gap + cross button width).